# Java pretty print XML version=1.0 with no quote

Tags: java, xml, serialization, declaration, quote

I've a xml string code. This string could be well formatted or not, and I should return a well format xml string.

I used this code and it was working great:

```
try {
            final Document document = parseXmlFile(code);
                OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(document);
            format.setLineWidth(65);
            format.setIndenting(true);
            format.setIndent(2);
            Writer out = new StringWriter();
            XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(out, format);
            serializer.serialize(document);
            newcode = out.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
private Document parseXmlFile(String in) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(in));
        return db.parse(is);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

but I found a bug for xml string with this declaration:

> ```
> <?xml version=
> ```
>
> 1.0
>    encoding=
>   utf-8
>   ?>

Here is the given error:

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.**

I tried also with this code, but i got the same error:

```
private static String prettyFormat(String input, int indent) {
    try {
        Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(input));
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", indent);
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
        return xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // simple exception handling, please review it
    }
}
```

Have you got any ideas how I could fix it? Possibly without removing the original declaration.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not a valid declaration. The parser only knows how to read valid xml. Where does your xml come from?

Comment: A standard XML parser will not handle malformed documents, as was already mentioned. TagSoup is a parser that's designed to try and make sense of malformed input.